# Is it possible to set an Outlook addin for the web to maintain focus?

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

We are building an Outlook addin which will gather additional information about an Event. We would like it to pop up in Outlook web version and maintain control, so they cannot continue working on the event before they either save or cancel the add-in window. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. You need to use the [Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui) for that. Read more about dialog APIs in the [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.

Comment: This is what we are using - but we were hoping to find something that was NOT independent of the application, and as such could "force" the user to save or cancel the operation before returning to the application.

Comment: There are no such tools.